# Laravel 5 form request merge input into rules

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

What I do not understand is why the rules do not pick up the merged input. Here is the rules method:

```
public function rules(Event_Segment $segment)
{
    $segment = $segment->where('event_id', $this->input('event'));
    $this->merge(['run' => $segment->count(), 'publish' => $segment->where('publish', 1)->count()]);
    return [
        'event' => 'exists:fed_event,id,fed_id,' . $this->route('id') . ',run,2',
        'run' => 'required|same:publish'
    ];
}
```

When I submit the form an error comes back saying that `run` is required.

Comment: That means you are submitting a empty input field form your form. Or make sure the input field's name is 'run' in your form.